# Giving a tag a name and calling in if isset function

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have to say three hyperlinks, of which I have given them names for redirection
depending on the link clicked.
The page of the request is one but with different content(dynamism).
here are my codes:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_GET['class'])){
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE class = class1";
       header("location: subjects.php");
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['class2'])){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE class = class2";
              header("location: subjects.php");
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['class3'])){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE class = class3";
              header("location: subjects.php");
    }
    else{
    header("location: classes.php");
    }
?>
```

This is the html hyperlinks with a name:

```
<a href="" name="class1"> Class 1 </a>
<a href="" name="class2"> Class 2 </a>
<a href="" name="class3"> Class 3 </a>
```

Comment: I'm confused at what you're asking. Is this not working correctly?

Comment: you cannot use name as an attribute of an a tag hoping to send it to another page. Using an a tag you need to use the href attribute and pass it into the query string part of the url

Answer (score 1):

A `form` builds the `GET` request with the `name` attribute as the parameter. With your approach you need to build the `GET` in the `href`, the `name` won't process as it does with a `form`.

```
<a href="?class1=true" name="class1"> Class 1 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `decide.php` be the name of your PHP script file name then below will be the HTML of your hyper-links:

```
<a href="decide.php?class1=" name="class1"> Class 1 </a>
<a href="decide.php?class2=" name="class2"> Class 2 </a>
<a href="decide.php?class3=" name="class3"> Class 3 </a>
```